# while loop, is looping results instead of through the questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, while-loop

im creating a number guessing game in node , but my while loop is suppose to loop through the question (Please guess a number between 0-maxNum, when the answer previously guessed is incorrect. ) I have made it so if the ranNum is not equal too number guessed loop, ive added a break for the statement if it is true, but i cannot seem to figure it out if anyone has any idea that could help!)

```
let maxNum= readlineSync.question(name +" "+'choose a number between ' + 0 
        +" 
         "+ ' and ' +  number + '\n') 
        //   }
    if (maxNum > number) {
    console.log(`You cannot use a number greater than ` + number)

  let ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum) + 1; 

      while(ranNum !== number) 
     {

         if (number === ranNum) {
           console.log('Correct! The number was ' + ranNum)
        break;
    } else if ( ranNum >  number) {
        console.log('Close! Too high.');
    } else if ( ranNum < number) {
        console.log('Almost! Too low.');
    }
}
     }
    }
```

Comment: nothing changes inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to make a while loop this will make you stuck in the loop when the answer is incorrect.

i think this code is making the same thing that you want to make.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var MAX = 50;
    var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;
    function test(){
    var number = parseInt(document.forms["form"]["in"].value);
        if (number == ranNum) {
            alert('Correct! The number was ' + ranNum)
        } else if ( ranNum >  number) {
            alert('Close! Too high.');
        } else if ( ranNum < number) {
            alert('Almost! Too low.');
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name = "form" onsubmit = "test()">
        <input type = "textarea" name = "in" />
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

i hope this answer you question.